# Notepad++ regex replacements, with several occurences on the same line, won't work

Tags: regex, replace

Trying to batch clean a lot of HTML, having all `a href="url"` blanked, replaced with only `a href=""`

In Notepad++, *Search and Replace*, I tried the regex :

```
href=.*"
```

That only works when there is just one a `href=` per line.

In case of multiple a `href=` on the same line, the text selected by my regex expression starts with the first `a href="` , takes every following string of text, including several other `a href="url"` parts, and ends with the final `"` double quotes.

I didn't manage to google for better than my typical regex.

Comment: Forgot to mention: the same goes with replacing everything between double quotes, ".*"

Comment: Try to replace `href\s*=\s*("[^"]+"|'[^']+')` with `href=""`, considering some of them might use single quotes. `.*` is greedy (`.*?` is lazy) and will match *as much as possible* and since you probably have multiple line match disabled this is why it fails. In a string like `abcabcabcabcabc` using a regex like `c.*b` you will get `cabcabcabcab` whereas `c.*?b` will get you `cab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [non-greedy repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) instead:

```
href=.*?"
```

Comment: Ah, thank you Ndn! I never ran into that problem before, and I didn't know about the greedy repetition problem. I've learnt something today :) I just tested, your simple replacement of ".*" with ".*?" worked :)

Comment: Thanks, this answer saved my day. You just add a ? and all problems solved, lol...

Answer (score 1):

Since `href` attributes can be enclosed in either single or double quotes, use matching groups to see which one it was enclosed with.

Next, use a non-greedy match so as to match as small a string as possible:

```
(href=)(['"])[^\2]+?\2
```

and then, replace them with

```
\1\2\2           (or $1$2$2)
```

Comment: Thanks Hjpotter92, but that wasn't an issue with the other forms of quotes. I was simply unaware of the greedy repetition problem, as I'm self-taught and I never stumbled upon this problem before. I've learnt something today, simply replacing *finalstring with *?finalstring in my regex did the trick :)